# Rose::DB::Object::Manager query with a list of object ids

Tags: perl, rose-db-object

I'm trying to write a Rose::DB::Object query string using either an Array or a Hash, however I'm unsure how to do it.  I'm trying to write an update function based off of certain ID's in a list that are enumerated in the array. I unfortunately do not have any other unique key to filter on to build the query, so I need to query specific ID's.

Essentially I am trying to programatically write the follow:

```
my $list = My::DB::Manager->get_items(query => [
     {id => 1},
     {id => 14},
     {id => 210},
     {id => 1102},
     {id => 3151},
]);
```

This is the code I have so far, but I haven't been able to successfully achieve what I am trying to do:

```
        use My::DB::Manager;
        my @ary;
        foreach (@_) {
            my %col = ("id", $_);
            push (@ary, \%col);
        }
        my $list = My::DB::Manager->get_items(query => \@ary);
        ...
```

./test.pl

Now the script just hangs with no output indefinately.

I'm trying to avoid iterating through the DB::Manager and making a DB call on a per record basis as this script will be run via cron every 60 seconds and has the potential to return large sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`query`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Manager.pm#query) parameter takes a reference to an array of name/value pairs, not a reference to an array of hash references.  If you want objects where the value of the `id` column is one of a list of values, then use the name `id` and a reference to an array of ids as the value. This code should work (assuming the id values are in `@_`):

```
$list = My::DB::Manager->get_items(query => [ id => \@_ ]);
```

Comment: That worked!, It threw an error for the elements in my array which is collected from a Sybase SQL query and the results have \x00 appended to each element in the array which is causing the Oracle query I am using Rose::DB for to fail. Hopefully Rose::DB will get Sybase support.

Answer (score 0):

You push strings into `@ary` when you need to push perl structures:

```
    use My::DB::Manager;
    my @ary;
    foreach (@_) {
            push (@ary, { id => $_ });
    }
    my $list = My::DB::Manager->get_items(query => [@ary]);
    ...
```

However, I think you can use `query => [ id => [$id1, $id2, ... ], ...]`:

```
    use My::DB::Manager;
    my $list = My::DB::Manager->get_items(query => [ id => \@_ ]);
    ...
```

Never used Rose, this based on docs of the module.

Comment: I tried the above as well but any way I attempt it I get an invalid query string.  I almost suspect that I need a hash, but not sure how to use a hash since "id" would be a duplicate key.